# Losing class context when calling function by reference

Tags: javascript, async-await

I've got a library that makes api calls to a number of sub-api's. If I call a function directly all works great:

```
let result = await apiLib.subApi1.getFoo();
```

But if I call by reference, I seem to lose the class context (i.e. 'this' is undefined within the class)

```
const endPoint = 'Foo';
let apiLibCall = apiLib.subApi1['get' + endPoint];
let result = await apiLibCall();
```

Is it possibly because of how 'await' works? Or am I calling by reference incorrectly?

Comment: Either call it directly `await apiLib.subApi1['get' + endPoint]()`. Or if you want to assign it to a variable, you need to `bind` the correct `this` like : `let apiLibCall = apiLib.subApi1['get' + endPoint].bind(apiLib.subApi1)`. Please check the duplicates on how `this` keyword works.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to check for duplicates, but they do indeed answer my question